# VB Error with Lambda expression: cannot be converted to 'Expression(Of Func(Of I, O))'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, expression

I have a method defined as the following:

```
Public Function Expression(expr As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, [Object]))) As TFactory
```

It's a method that allows the user to define an expression within the model.  It's used like the following in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project:

```
Expression(Function(i) i.Persons(index).FirstName)
```

i.Persons is a 'List(Of IPersonEntity)' on the model, so obviously I'm doing collection binding.  However, in VB, it gives the error:

> Lambda expression cannot be converted to
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of IPersonEntity,
>   Object))' because 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Func(Of IPersonEntity, Object))' is not a delegate type.

This doesn't make any sense because it's the common technique used... but why am I getting an error?  When the application runs, it works just fine.  But it's causing me issues at design-time in my ASP.NET MVC view...

Comment: Change the function name, or change the line to `Me.Expression(Function(i) i.Persons(index).FirstName)`, the problem by the looks of it is name conflict.

Comment: Change the name of the method, but the problem still exists...